When writing to the clipboard in JavaScript, is it possible to set a custom sourceURL?
The sourceURL property is set automatically by Chrome. Is it possible to override this and set it to a different value?
For debugging, I'd like to set sourceURL to a specific value. But I don't even know if it is possible to affect the clipboard content before "Startfragment".
